# Keeping used/dirty clothes in suitcase

Tags: clothing, personal-care

While travelling with one bag/suitcase. What is the best way to keep dirty/used clothes in bag along clothes with clean/new clothes.

Answer (score 9):

I always bring a large kitchen trash bag in my suitcase when I travel. At the end of each day, I put my dirty clothes in the trash bag (and close it, if it has a drawstring). When I re-pack my suitcase to go home at the end of the trip, I put any clean clothes in the bottom of the suitcase, then put the closed trash bag full of dirty clothes on top of it. The plastic trash bag keeps the clean clothes from getting dirty, and it also helps me unpack quickly at home:  I just take the bag out and empty it right into my laundry hamper.

Answer (score 2):

Get a suitcase with a zip cover on each side. The clothes get put in the dirty side once you've worn them. They stay separate (unless you forget to zip one side up before you close it of course).

Answer (score 1):

I use separate (ziplock) bags, for smelly/dirty clothing, for used but can be used again and for small items of clothing that tend to get lost between the bigger items.

When you do your laundry while traveling you fold the bags and store them till you get the same level of dirt again.

Instead of ziplock bags you can also use the thin nylon shopping bags or wash bags which are quite easy to get these days.
A [slightly longer version on Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/78166/27650) and the other answers to the same question might help you as well, even though the question is not a duplicate.

Comment: Yeah, I only throw the dirty clothes inside plain nylon shopping bags then stash them in the same bag/suitcase with everything else. Works well, as long as the nylon bags are not torn of course.

Answer (score 1):

Use a cloth bag so the clothes can breathe. If you use a plastic bag they'll be a bit icky after a few days. If you have one with handles or a drawstring you can hang it up tidily. Those cloth shopping bags are good for this.

If you don't have a cloth bag handy use a pillow case, or a used T-shirt.

Comment: If you put your real dirty dirties in a bag where they can breathe, they will get the rest of your clothes dirty.

Comment: Goodness! I never got them that dirty on holiday.

Answer (score 1):

Nylon bags are really good point for humid climate. I used plastic bags in Thailand and got actual mould on my dirty laundry. Then switched to nylon bags and solved this. Also, many hotels have free nylon laundry bags.

Plastic trash bags work well in dry climate.